# Adding groups to scope for Auth Code Flow pt. 1

Tags: api, authentication, session, token, onelogin

The docs say "Add “profile” and/or “groups” to get additional user information returned in the id_token". How? What format? When I do the following:

https://.onelogin.com/oidc/2/auth?client_id=&redirect_uri=&response_type=code&scope=openid,groups

I get an error saying openid is required, as if it didn't recognize it because I tacked on the ',groups' to the querystring. What do they mean by "add" in the docs?

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code

Comment: Yeah pretty hard to say they don't even provide example requests. I would try with spaces instead e.g. `?scope=openid%20groups`. Next bet would be arrays `?scope=openid&scope=groups`.